# Trying to make an automated email response when my professor either accepts or denies a project proposal

Tags: google-apps-script

Can't seem to figure out how to make it so it emails the person without specifying the email through sendmail. Help is massively appreciated!

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  // Event Variable
      let range = e.range;
      let row = e.range.getRow();
      let col = e.range.getColumn();
      let cellValue = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue();
      let studentEmail = sheet.getRange(row,6).getValue();

  if(col==7&&cellValue=="Accepted")
{
  MailApp.sendEmail(studentEmail,"Status update on your Capstone Project","Your project has been accepted by Ms. x.")
  }
}
```

Comment: Since sending emails requires permission you will need to use an installable trigger and do not name the handler onEdit otherwise you will get two trigger the simple and the installable

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

I did not test it

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart == 7 && e.value == "Accepted") {
    MailApp.sendEmail(e.range.offset(0, -1).getValue(), "Status update on your Capstone Project", "Your project has been accepted by Ms. x.")
  }
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [onEdit.restrictions()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)
- [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)